# focusnode is not working in flutter textformfield?

Tags: flutter, dart

when change==true the focus node is not working ,When I click the add button in the app bar i want to focus textfield

> I want to focus the text field ,Can anyone fix this? Thank you[image]

the sample image

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool change = false;
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNode2 = FocusNode();
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
     
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(actions: [
       IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  change = true;
                });
                focusNode.unfocus();
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
                const SizedBox(width: 141,)  ]),
        body: Center(
          child: Center(
            child: change == false
                ? const Text("data")
                : TextFormField(
                    focusNode: focusNode,
                    decoration:
                        const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because you set `change` to false when you press the button and then never turn `change` back to true.

Comment: when i tap the button the textfield is appearing but not focusing..can you check it out again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build frame on `change` can take frame, try adding postFrameCallback

```dart
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    change = true;
  });
  focusNode.unfocus();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
  });
},
```

Comment: i really appreciate it..can you tell me why we need to add " addPostFrameCallback " here in simple words?

Comment: once you tap,   `change = true` and request the focus but TextField isn't  ready yet ig